Bash functions echo differently to stdout when sourced vs. forked
I have a bash script initial-tests.bash that runs some tests, using another script with pure functions. It looks something like:
#! /bin/bash

source ./scripts/_functions.bash

check=$(do_check)

echo "$check"

The script _functions.bash contains this:
#! /bin/bash
# Here we save reusable functions to aid the other scripts

echoerr() {
    # Output to stderr while freeing stdout for returns
    echo -ne $red
    echo "ERROR: $*" | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' 1>&2
    echo -ne $nc
}

first_check() {
  echoerr "This is an echoerr with echo -e"
  echo false
}

do_check() {
  local x
  x=$(first_check)

  if [[ "$x" = 'false' ]]; then
    echo
  else
    echo false
  fi
}

initial-tests.bash is in turn sourced by another script main.bash:
#! /bin/bash

nc='\e[0m'
yellow='\e[1;33m'
green='\e[1;32m'
red='\e[1;31m'
blue='\e[1;34m'


# Fail early in case of argumentation error
echo -e "${blue}- - - Initial Checks - - -${nc}"
source ./scripts/initial-checks-load-config.bash

The tests' outputs are correct when I source that script directly: source scripts/initial-tests.bash:
[2024-10-10 08:30:55] ERROR: This is an echoerr with echo -e


But when I run bash main.bash, the tests are wrong:
- - - Initial Checks - - -
[2024-10-10 08:30:49] ERROR: This is an echoerr with echo -e
false

Note that false should be empty.
It is not clear to me why source is producing a different result from the bash run.
More info:

OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.8.0-1015-azure x86_64)
Bash: GNU bash, version 5.2.21(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)


A child process can't set variables in a way that persists into the parent. This isn't unique to bash, or to Linux -- part of the general UNIX process model is that processes, unlike threads, get their own memory (based on the parent's but copy-on-write so changes don't propagate back). Thus it's completely normal that sourcing a script leaves behind variables it set, but running it in a subprocess doesn't.

@CharlesDuffy Can you please clarify your point? the tests echo directly without affecting parent process env. When I bash main.bash, and source initial-tests.bash from within, the latter script should still run in the same process as the "sourcer" script. The results are echoed from the sourced script in both cases, so I am not echoing them from the parent process but from the subprocess..

This is one of those questions where there's too much information so it's hard to see the forest for the trees. Can you reduce your code and input/output to a [mcve] that concisely demonstrates just the problem you're asking for help with? You don't need multiple functions and multiple lines of code per function and 20 lines in the calling script and multiple color escape sequences, etc. to demonstrate the problem and it's important to our understanding of the problem for the line numbers in the error messages to match the code you show us.

First, and most importantly -- Ed is right. A [mre] with the shortest possible code that causes the same problem when run without changes would give us a much more answerable question. My first comment was based on a cell-phone read where we saw that your problems were caused by variables not being set; when you run foo=$(bar) it's normal for any variable set within bar to be gone by the time foo is assigned, hence that point being made. Anyhow -- there's still not enough clarity in the question to allow a proper answer, but some notes about other aspects of the code at hand:

(1) Don't use local foo=$(do_foo); local bar=$(do_bar). Instead, set local foo bar baz at the top of your function and then foo=$(do_foo) &c later; that way you don't have the exit status of local itself overriding that of the do_* commands.

(2) Consider avoiding echo -e for the reasons given by Stephane in the [unix.se] question Why is printf better than echo?. printf %b gives you much more fine-detailed control about which specific parts of your string have values that are or aren't interpreted as format strings, and is far more portable.

(3) Similarly for portability reasons, avoid function, which bash only offers for compatibility with 1980s-era ksh. foo() { is more portable than function foo { (though they're both better than function foo() {). Doesn't matter when your code is only running on bash, but the function keyword can mess you up either on sh (where it isn't guaranteed to exist at all) or on ksh (where its behavior is slightly different from that of a POSIX-compliant function definition).

Coming back to topic -- I suspect you have unexported variables set in the shell that you either source or call your script from. If your database server's hostname &c aren't exported, they don't survive a fork so child processes can't see them (and so the script can only use those variables when source'd into the current shell); but because you haven't given us a [mre], that's just guesswork -- we can't confirm it.

BTW, the easy way to distinguish whether you have unexported content is to run declare -p. Where the output contains declare -x varname='value' something is exported and visible to child processes; where it's declare -- varname='value' that variable is unexported and won't remain available across an execve boundary.

(That's not the only state that doesn't survive an execv boundary -- you also lose shopt options, $- flags, and similar; again, we really need a [mre] to pin this down because right now we don't know which options are set and relevant in the parent shell).

Shellcheck identifies several problems with the code in the question.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run Shellcheck on all new and modified shell code.

Thank you all, I am creating a MRE, and sorry for including too much info. I appreciate you taking the time to give me advices nonetheless.

@pjh thanks, integrated it into VS Code

As I was minimising the code, I found that echoerr function I have, which made use of the unreliable echo -e and echo -ne options, was somehow ruining my functions' stdout values which I used later in if checks. It was therefore causing inconsistencies between source and bash runs. Eliminating all echo -e / echo -ne uses fixes the problem. I will post an answer tomorrow after I make sure this is the case with more testing.

Logs meant for human readers should always go to stderr -- make sure you have >&2 on those lines to keep them separate from stdout.

It seems that my problem is a mixture of:

Unsourced variables not available to initial-tests.bash in case it is run directly and not via main.bash (the colour escape sequences)
Using echo -ne $nc as the last command in echoerr, which is not outputting a newline character and thus, in effect, is prepending $nc to the echo that immediately follows in first_check function.

Regarding point 1, when I run bash main.bash and then source initial-tests.bash, the sourced script will have access to the colour escape sequences. But when I directly source initial-tests.bash, and since the colour sequences are not (re-)defined within, these colour sequences are blank.
Regarding point 2, using -n prepends to next echo:
echo -n hi; echo bye
> hibye

When $nc is blank due to sourcing initial-tests.bash directly as explained, function first_check is producing a mere false since nothing is prepended to 'false' because $nc is empty:
echo -ne $nc (last command in echoerr)
echo false

And the if test in do_check passes:
if [[ "$x" = 'false' ]]; then
    echo
else
    echo false
fi

=> so output is ''.
However, when I run bash main.bash, $nc contains a colour escape sequence, so that sequence is prepended to false and is making the same test fail, and hence going to the else, and echoing 'false' instead of nothing => so output is 'false'. It was tricky to detect since the prepended value was an escape sequence.
I could fix this by:

Making sure the colour sequences vars are always available before using them
Removing echo -n from echoerr to avoid prepending anything to the immediate next echo.


the -n option to echo just causes it to NOT output a newline after whatever it outputs.  There's no prepending going on.  Unlike in C programs, there's no buffering happening -- output just goes to fd 1 when it goes.

Understood. Perhaps I used imprecise language to explain what was happening specifically in my code. See the example about echo -n hi; echo bye where, eventually, the result looks like prepending in effect. I will amend the sentence to be more precise.

This is as expected.
When you run initial-tests.bash, the environment variables $red and $nc are unset.  So stdout from echoerr is empty, and stdout from first_check is just the 5-character string false.
When you run main.bash, it first sets nc='\e[0m' andred='\e[1;31m', so stdout from echoerr will be those strings, and stdout from first_check (which is captured as $x) will thus be \e[1;31m\e[0mfalse which is not the same as false (though it likely appears the same on the terminal)
I think your error is likely thinking that the color-output escapes will immediately change the color, but they do not -- they are just strings that are output to stdout.  They only have an effect when they actually get to the terminal.  It is likely that what you really want is to redirect them to stderr in echoerr:
echoerr() {
    # Output ALL of this to stderr, nothing to stdout.
    echo -ne $red >&2
    echo "ERROR: $*" | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' >&2
    echo -ne $nc >&2
}


That was an issue that would have made both executions wrong, and I noted it out in my answer. Thank you for the note about the colour-output sequences and stderr redirection! +1


why source is producing a different result from the bash run.

It's probably because that source executes scripts in the current shell environment, while bash runs the script in a new subshell. This can lead to differences in the way variables and setting.
Potential problem: When you source the scripts/initial-tests.bash directly, the environment remains the same, and also several variable assignments are accessible as they are part of the current shell. However, when you run main.bash, the initial-tests.bash script is sourced in a subshell, and since several variable is declared in main.bash, it is not available to _functions.bash.
What you can try to check that several variables are accessible when _functions.bash is sourced and used. Alternatively, ensure main.bash sources _functions.bash before any function calls, so that the variables are accessible.

Understood, I indeed had unsourced variables which needed to be redefined or made available before being used as I indicated in my answer. I found it useful to use declare -p to check the variables' state while running scripts, as @Charles pointed out in his comment.

So, you're saying it's an answer?

It is part of the answer, check this previous answer which is tried and works
